# Rails query not returning updated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Rails is not returning the updated version of a record.

I have two methods in a model, `submit_job(sig, label, jobtype)` for submitting a job to a db that will get processed on the backend, and then `poll_result(id)` which will poll that submitted job every second to see when it completes, and then return the results from the completed job to the user.

My issue is that the `poll_result(id)` method is never getting the updated record.

```
def self.poll_result(id)

    change = false
    Workbench.where("id = ?", id).each do |sig|         
        if sig.resultsready.to_i == 1
            change = true
        end
    end
    return change
end
```

All this does is comeback with the results from my original insert over and over, as I can see when I have it print out the results of the record it is accessing. I am looking directly at the database and can see that it is calling the right ID, and that the record has been updated. resultsready is set to 1 in the database, the loop should end and it should return back, but it just gets stuck in an infinite loop.

My assumption is that it is somehow getting an old/stale record that is being cached somehow, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to force it to get the new record.

Thank You,

-Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Workbench.connection.clear_query_cache` fixed the issue! To be specific, I added it at the controller level, right before calling `Workbench.poll_result(id)`